# Building and running a finished project on iOS

Tags: react-native

I have a project downloaded from GIT in React-Native

What steps should I take to run the application in Debug mode on iOS:

- on Emulator
- on my Device

Comment: go to ios folder and open .xcworkspace extension in xcode and also download the cocoapods by going to appdirectory/ios and then pod install . after that in top left just check for emulator or real device in xcode and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, install the node_modules using npm or yarn as per the git project readme.

If your react native version is above 60, it get default cocoapods support. Move to ios folder and run pod install from commandline.

Now you have 2 options to run the project:
1. Navigate to ios folder and run the command 'react-native run-ios'.
2. Open Xcode,Navigate to ios folder and open projecname.xcworkspace file. You can see the run command on top-left of the IDE.